# How to get a date_range boundary on script on Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

How can I access to a date_range field boundary on a script?

I tried to access the field with

```
doc['field.gte']
```

and get `No field found for [field.gte] in mapping`

Also, I debug the class of the field

```
Debug.explain(doc['status.dates'])
```

and get org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.ScriptDocValues.Strings.

Furthermore, I debug the class of the field value

```
Debug.explain(doc['status.dates'].value)
```

and get java.lang.String class

Comment: You should get both values with `doc['status.dates'].values`

Comment: `doc['status.dates'].values` throws me an `illegal_argument_exception`with message `Illegal list shortcut value [values].`